# Positioning in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
l={2 x, x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x}
```

I want to pick those elements that have coefficients bigger than 1, i.e. `{2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 4 x, 2 x}`
I tried

```
Select[CoefficientList[{2 x, x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x}, 
    x][[All, 2]], # > 1 &]*x
```

which return what I need but I believe there must be a much shorter and faster way? Also I would like to find the position of `{2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 4 x, 2 x}` in my original list so I did:

```
Position[{2 x, x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x}, {2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 
  4 x, 2 x}]
```

which does not work so I must be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = {2 x, x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x};

s = Select[CoefficientList[l, x][[All, 2]], # > 1 &]*x

p = Position[l, Alternatives @@ Union[s]]
```

> {{1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {10}}

```
Extract[l, p]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
Pick[l,Exponent[x,l],0]
```

> {2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 4 x, 2 x}

or

```
Flatten[Take[l,#]&/@Position[Exponent[x,l],0]]
```

Also if you want the positions try

```
Position[Exponent[x, l], 0]
```

> {{1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {10}}

Answer (score 5):

You might do like this:

```
l /. x -> 1 /. x_ /; x == 1 -> Nothing /. a_ -> a*x
(*   {2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 4 x, 2 x}   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

```
l={2 x, x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x};
Pick[l, Unitize[D[l, x] - 1], 1]
```

> {2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 4 x, 2 x}

```
  Flatten@Position[Unitize[D[l, x] - 1], 1]
```

> {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}

Answer (score 3):

```
l = {2 x, x, 4 x, -x, x, 2 x, 4 x, x, x, 2 x};
test = Clip[Coefficient[l, x], {1, 1}, {1, 0}]; (* 1 means coeffient <= 1, else 0 *)
l2 = Pick[l, test, 0]
pos = Ordering[test, Length[l2]]
```

> {2 x, 4 x, 2 x, 4 x, 2 x}
>   {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}